# Power BI Text to Long Date Errors For Data Model

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have Sales table and this table contains OrderDate column this column foreign key. And i have Dates table this table has date column i want to connect for this two table on orderDate and date column. But orderDate columns type is text and i did'nt change the type how can i do this ?

[image]

Comment: You must change the type of orderDate. Keeping it text will make this model almost useless.

Comment: When i try yo change data type then i get this error; **We cant automatically convert the column to Date type.**

Comment: I tried also SSMS with this code `SELECT CAST(OrderDate as date) as StringToDate FROM Sales` and i get his error : **Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. **

Comment: Could u try this one ?Go2 data transformation screen and open "Applied Steps" menu on the right of ur screen, delete steps till navigation. Change your date split charc as ur computer default. finally change ur column data type to Date

Comment: I tried bu it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved hard way. I am gonna explain;
There is example data : **6 Haziran 2014 Cuma** I splitted this data like dd/mm/YYYY

```
Day=LEFT(Sales[OrderDate],SEARCH(" ",Sales[OrderDate])-1) 

Year = RIGHT(LEFT(Sales[OrderDate],SEARCH(" ",Sales[OrderDate],12)),5)
```

For Month i used conditional column. Like: each if Text.Contains([OrderDate], "Ocak") then 1 else if .....

And finally OrderDateForConnection = Sales[Day] & "/" & Sales[Month] & "/" & Sales[Year] and its worked :)